# Android Keeping Session Forever

Tags: android, authentication, synchronization, httpclient

Quite the opposite of what you might think I'm asking about. We ran into a small bug on a particular device in which it always fails to log into the site through an HTTPClient

```
public void Login() {
    final WebHandler webHandler = this;
    this.httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    this.thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // update local database
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(root);
            Login(prefs.getString(Keys.PREFERENCE.USERNAME, ""), prefs.getString(Keys.PREFERENCE.PASSWORD, ""));
            for (OnCompleteListener method : event_handler)
                method.onComplete(webHandler); // pop event

            Logout();
        }
    });
    this.thread.start();
}
public void Logout() {
    try {
        this.httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Domain + LOGOUT_URL);
        HttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null)
            Log.e("Logout()", e.getMessage());
        else
            Log.e("Logout()", e.toString());
    }
}
```

The idea was that a request would log into the site (even if it were already logged in), visit the page for information, and then log out. The problem we seem to be having with one of our devices (a chinese "gaming" tablet) is that it NEVER logs out. Even trying to login with faulty credentials, it is always allowed access to the site. I've run through the browser on the device and logged out, cleared data, etc. There is no logical explanation as to why this device is getting information from a login-locked website. I don't even know how to debug such a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Site was coded with Joomla, and it appears the page had no Access Level Restrictions, and defaulted to "Guest" user access. Changing this to "Employee" solved this problem.